# Controlling a power supply with a MOSFET

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, circuit-design

I'm making a circuit that will have a main part (up to 5A load) in a back box, mostly unreachable, and a control panel at the front.

I want to have a kill switch at the front panel, so that I won't have to reach for the back part, but I don't want to bring the main load wires there, so I was thinking of having a MOSFET control the circuit, and then I would only need the wires to control the gate and a switch at the front.

Here's my idea:
[image]

Only SW2 would be at the front (SW1 would be a backup at the back), and the two wires to connect it, with everything else at the back. VCC and ground would then connect to the rest of the back circuit.

Does this even work?

Comment: You want a high value resistor (say 10K) from gate to source to define the gate voltage with SW2 open. And I am assuming SW1 is safely accessible (if inconvenient) in the event Q1 fails dead short.

Comment: Consider using a high-side MOSFET in series with SW1 because if Q1 in your circuit is off while SW1 is on, the load is still being powered. What would happen if the load was shorted to ground elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.  You need a resistor from the gate to the source to guarantee that the FET turns off when the switch opens.  There is almost zero steady-state current in the off condition.  For the on condition, the lower the resistance, the less noise pickup that could lead to false triggering of the MOSFET, but the higher the power dissipation.  Consider 1 K, 1/2 W as a starting value.

A common rule of thumb for long-term reliability is 2:1.  Devices should be rated for a minimum of twice the conditions they will operate in.  Examples:

12 V circuit  --  30 V FET

5 A load  --  10 A FET

0.144 W dissipation  --  0.5 W resistor